# How to encapsulate multiple class in java?

Tags: java, exception

I have the following scenario.

```
public void foo() throws BadFooException, IOException{
    try{
            ..........
    } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException e) {
            throw new BadFooException(e);
    } catch(ArithmeticException e) {
            throw new BadFooException(e);
    }
}
```

Here `BadFooException` is a class that extends `Exception`. But to my desire `BadFooException` shall only catch

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException
```

and

```
ArithmeticException
```

not the other exceptions. I am always catching those two exception and throwing my desired exception. But is there any way, so that my desired exception will be thrown automatically in case of only these two exceptions but other exceptions will be thrown separately?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably a typo? `ArithmeticException`

Comment: Haven't you already made it so that your desired exception will be thrown in case of only these two exceptions? What does your code currently do that you don't want it to do? (or not do that you want it to do)

Comment: @immibis Actually, I did it, but I am not liking the way I have done it, So I asked for any other technique that I don't know yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite clear what you ask... However if you want to combine several exceptions, to save some typing work, you could use:

```
public void foo() throws CustomException1, OtherException {
    try {
        // stuff (that can throw Exception1, Exception2 and OtherException)
    } catch (Exception1 | Exception2 ex) {
        throw new CustomException1(ex);
    }
}
```

Thus with a vertical bar in between.

As far as I know, there is no more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Thanks. 
But what I asked is, is there any way so that I don't have to use the try catch block.

Comment: Not as far as I know, why is this a problem?